# bringSubViewToFront , sendViewToBack , Interface Builder , help !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, viewdidload, loadview

If I have the views added in Interface Builder and not as addSubView in program
Can Use bringSubViewToFront , sendViewToBack? 
do I need to define loadView in order to use them
Because I am trying to use it in ViewDidLoad but it returns undefined method.

I have some views in IB I want to send it back? bring other View in front using some boolean variables ? IS that possible in IB or I have to use bringSubViewToFront , sendViewToBack methods? How to use these methods in my case?
many thanks

Comment: For your uiViews in IB did you create IBOutlets in your code and connected them correctly in IB?

Comment: yes, I have the bringViewToFront works now.

Comment: However I have a problem with UITextField when I am implementing  self.myTextField.hidden = FALSE;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:destinationTextField]; is not showing ? is there something special to show or hide TextField other than these methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the methods are:

```
-bringSubviewToFront
-sendSubviewToBack
-viewDidLoad
-addSubview
```

You can set the hierarchy by the ordering of the views in Interface Builder.

Comment: i didn't get u. can u explain, what do u mean by set the hierarchy  ?

Comment: self.myTextField.hidden = FALSE;
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTextField]; is not bringing it to the front , what  could be the problem. plz note that the hidden is not checked in IB